# Connectionstring Access

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

What is the best way to get Connection String from Web.config files. I know it can be used in  Global.asax  in App_start

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static 
   readonly string ConnectionString = "connection information";

    . . .    
}
```

But, how to you get the static variable in Multiple Assemblies.

Let say i have 4 assemblies for my web application  ( UI, Service Layer, Business Layer, Data Layer ) and i want access to DataLayer (which is a separate assembly),

I don't want to put the config reading in Datalayer Constructor.

I wanted to use the HttpApplictionvariable / static variable to read the connection string value in Datalayer.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: "I wanted to use the HttpApplictionvariable / static variable to read the connection string value in Datalayer.", This is **wrong approach**. You are making your layers tightly coupled with ASP.Net. What if you have to use your layers in different applications like WinForm or WPF ? You shouldn't do that. Passing the connection string to your constructor is a better approach, IMHO.

Comment: Im not using Entity Framework

Answer (score 0):

You could create a contract for your settings:

```
public IApplicationSettings
{
    string ConnectionString { get; }

    // any other setting variable 
}
```

And than use this abstraction in your code

```
public class MyRepository 
{ 
    private string conncetionString;

    public MyRepository(IApplicationSettings settings)
    {
         this.conncetionString = settings.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

In this way you will hide any dependency to stuff like `ConfigurationManager` and the way how you storing settings in app. If your are using IoC, you will have control on instance life time.